# Как отформатировать время так, чтобы все лишнее отсекалось?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, время

Есть такой код:

```
DateTime starttime = DateTime.UtcNow;
...
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - starttime;
...     
Label1.Text = ts.TotalSeconds.ToString("00:##");
```

Но при таком форматировании выводит следующее: `Прошло: 00.30`, а мне бы хотелось чтобы время само считало, нужно ему добавить часы или убрать минуты, вот так: `Прошло: 1 час 20 минут 34 секунды.` А когда час еще не наступил или минута, то вот так: `Прошло: 50 минут 29 секунд` или `Прошло: 45 секунд`. Можно ли это как-то реализовать?

Comment: Если интересуетесь не с целью обучения, а с целью "как сделать", то мой совет, используйте готовые решения, а не изобретайте велосипед. Например, [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer). Если с целью обучения, то проект открыт, можете посмотреть как сделано там.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да можно

```
TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.UtcNow - starttime;
string message = "Прошло: ";
if (elapsed.TotalHours >= 1)
{
    message += $"{(int)elapsed.TotalHours} час {(int)elapsed.Minutes} минут {(int)elapsed.Seconds} секунд";
}
else if (elapsed.TotalMinutes >= 1)
{
    message += $"{(int)elapsed.TotalMinutes} минут {(int)elapsed.Seconds} секунд";
}
else
{
    message += $"{(int)elapsed.TotalSeconds} секунд";
}
Label1.Text = message;
```

Comment: Можно проще, без `else` и в обратном порядке, добавляя в строку минуты и часы, а вместо приведения к целому `(int)` лучше использовать форматирование `{elapsed.TotalHours:F0}`

Comment: ну или так проще)